# Has this usage of async / await in C# been discovered before?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2012, monads, async-await

After a previous question on stackoverflow regarding async / await it seemed to me that await was much more powerful and general than the marketing suggested. It seems to be a general method of building computation expressions just like in F#. So after a bit of a struggle I came up with some code that successfully executes as below.

```
    using FluentAssertions;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace EnumerableViaAwait.Specs
    {
        [global::Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClass]
        public class MyTestClass
        {
            public IEnumerable<int> Numbers()
            {
                return EnumeratorMonad.Build<int>(async Yield =>
                {
                    await Yield(11);
                    await Yield(22);
                    await Yield(33);
                });
            }

            [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod]
            public void TestEnum()
            {
                var v = Numbers();
                var e = v.GetEnumerator();

                int[] expected = { 11, 22, 33 };

                Numbers().Should().ContainInOrder(expected);

            }

        }
    }
```

Now carefully note what is going on here. I am **NOT** building a reactive observable. I am building an IEnumerable. It is strictly a pull system. I can quite happily write.

```
    foreach item in Numbers(){
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

and it will print out

```
    11
    22
    33
```

This is very interesting because the system is not strictly asynchronous but I'm abusing the await framework and the ability to "await anything" as outlined here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx.The *question(s)* are.

1. How far can this abuse of await / async go?
2. Is this pattern as powerfull as F# computation expressions
3. Is traditional IEnumerator / Yield pattern just syntactic sugar that evaluates
          exactly to this pattern

The code implementing the pattern is below

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace EnumerableViaAwait
    {

        public class EnumeratorMonad<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T>
        {
            public class Yield
            {
                private EnumeratorMonad<T> _Monad;

                public Yield(EnumeratorMonad<T> monad)
                {
                    _Monad = monad;
                }

                public YieldAwaiter GetAwaiter()
                {
                    return new YieldAwaiter(_Monad);
                }
            }

            public class YieldAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
            {
                EnumeratorMonad<T> _Monad;

                public YieldAwaiter(EnumeratorMonad<T> monad)
                {
                    _Monad = monad;
                }

                public bool IsCompleted
                {
                    get { return _Monad.IsCompleted(); }
                }

                public void GetResult()
                { }

                public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
                {
                    _Monad.Next = continuation; 
                }

            }

            private bool Completed { get; set; }

            public EnumeratorMonad()
            {
                Completed = false;
            }

            public bool IsCompleted()
            {
                return Completed;
            }

            public void Build(Func<Func<T, Yield>, Task> action)
            {
                Func<T, Yield> yielder = (T value) => { 
                    _Current = value;
                    return new Yield(this);
                };
                Next = async () => { 
                    await action(yielder);
                    Completed = true;
                };
            }

            private T _Current;
            public T Current
            {
                get { return _Current; }
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }

            object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
            {
                get { return _Current; }
            }


            Action Next;
            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                if (!Completed )
                {
                    Next();
                }
                return !Completed;
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }



            IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this;
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

        public class EnumeratorMonad{
            public static EnumeratorMonad<T> Build<T>(Func<Func<T, EnumeratorMonad<T>.Yield>, Task> action)
            {
                var monad = new EnumeratorMonad<T>();
                monad.Build(action);
                return monad;
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: The questions are in the middle. I guess you read the middle right?

Comment: +1 for finding this particularly interesting. :)

Comment: @bradgonesurfing, a prefix of 4 spaces on a line causes it to be formatted like code. You knew that...right?

Comment: You may be interested in [Jon Skeet's eduasync posts](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Eduasync/default.aspx).

Comment: Hi Stephen, your comment was the answer I was looking for. Jon Skeet is indeed doing evil stuff with async / await. If you make that link the answer then I'll mark it as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yield return` and `await`/`async` are just different specialized forms of coroutines. You've shown that you can (essentially) implement `yield return` using `await`/`async`, and I would not be surprised to find that it were possible the other way around. I'm sure that they are implemented in a very similar manner.

In practice, of course, I would not use `await`/`async` for iteration, since `yield return` is much simpler and more clear.

So,

1. You can probably take this "abuse" as far as you want.
2. Not sufficiently familiar with F# to answer.
3. No, but IIRC the features are implemented in more or less the same way.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is whether async/await are "specialized" or are they totally generic and can be used to implement more interesting workflows than just IEnumerator or Async. I don't think you can implement async / await in terms of yield return as yield return does not return an lvalue.

Comment: You're probably right in that you couldn't get the syntax as pretty the other way. As far as what you can do with them -- probably anything, but the best way to tell is to try it.

Comment: I'm going to try the Maybe monad next. I think I can write something like Do notation. The sequence should terminate early with Maybe::Nothing if any Maybe::Nothings are returned. It's not super pretty but it might be good for parsing XML

Comment: One *huge* benefit to this pattern - one that might make up for the reduction is readability - is that it allows you to create anonymous enumerable generators (as in the given example code), which the `yield return` keyword does not permit.